# Unable to access data from Rally wsapidatastore

Tags: javascript, rally

When I create a WsapiDataStore, store.data.items and store.data.keys return empty arrays although I am able to see the keys and items when I do console.log(store.data)

```
store = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'Defect',
    context: {
        project: '/project/xxxxxx'
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['Rank', 'FormattedID', 'Name']
});
```

Output of console.log(store.data):

```
constructor {items: Array[0], map: Object, keys: Array[0], length: 0, allowFunctions:   false…}
    allowFunctions: false
    events: Object
    generation: 8
    getKey: function (record) {
    hasListeners: HasListeners
    items: Array[7]
    keys: Array[7]
    length: 7
    map: Object
    sorters: constructor
    __proto__: TemplateClass
```

Notice how the first line says "items: Array[0]" and "keys: Array[0]" but when expanded it says "items: Array[7]" and "keys: Array[7]". I'm also able to see the 7 records when I expand further.

Everything works as expected when I add a load listener and access the data from the listener function (but I don't want to do that)

Comment: Bear in mind that AppSDK is asynchronous, so if you try to inspect elements of the store via console.log immediately after the create statement, you may not see anything. How come you don't want a listener? What is the end goal of your code? It's likely you'll need at least some event handling to accomplish your aim. If you could add a bit more context around where you're headed maybe there are some quick recommendations to be made.

Comment: My goal is to query data from user stories and defects and display it in a single grid. I was going to repeat the above code for a 'UserStory' model, save it in a variable and then concatenate store.data.items from both variables. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to process the data via two Rally.data.WsapiDataStore's. You'll need to chain the listeners for the two stores together in order to properly handle the asynchronous loads. Here's an example that illustrates the process:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MultipleModelExample</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                // Combined Story/Defect Records
                dataRecords: null,

                launch: function() {
                    //Write app code here

                    this.dataRecords = [];

                    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels({
                        types: ['HierarchicalRequirement','Defect'],
                        scope: this,
                        success: function(models) {
                            this.myModels = models;

                            this.storyStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                                model: models.HierarchicalRequirement,
                                fetch: true,
                                autoLoad: true,
                                remoteSort: true,
                                sorters: [
                                    { property: 'FormattedID', direction: 'Asc' }
                                ],
                                listeners: {
                                    load: this._processStories,
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },

                _processStories: function(store, records, successful, opts) {

                    var storyRecords = [];

                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) {
                        //Perform custom actions with the data here
                        //Calculations, etc.
                        storyRecords.push({
                            FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: record.get('Name'),
                            Description: record.get('Description')
                        });
                    });

                    this.dataRecords = storyRecords;

                    this.defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: this.myModels.Defect,
                        fetch: true,
                        autoLoad: true,
                        remoteSort: true,
                        sorters: [
                            { property: 'FormattedID', direction: 'Asc' }
                        ],
                        listeners: {
                            load: this._processDefects,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
                },

                _processDefects: function(store, records, successful, opts) {

                    var defectRecords = [];

                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) {
                        //Perform custom actions with the data here
                        //Calculations, etc.
                        defectRecords.push({
                            FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: record.get('Name'),
                            Description: record.get('Description')
                        });
                    });

                    var combinedRecords = defectRecords.concat(this.dataRecords);

                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                            data: combinedRecords,
                            pageSize: 25
                        }),
                        columnCfgs: [
                            {
                                text: 'FormattedID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 1
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'Description', flex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }

            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'MultipleModelExample'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
             /* Add app styles here */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess this chaining approach will work (although I would like to avoid a "global" variable, but I guess it's not a big deal). Thanks Mark!

Comment: One question though: Why do I need to use Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels? Why not just create a Wsapidatastore and chain it with another Wsapidatastore? Does it make a difference?

Comment: You could definitely do it without the ModelFactory. I only used it for the convenience of grabbing both Story and Defect models at the same time.